# Sinónimo para "patagio" incluido en el DLE

Tags: sustantivos, sinónimos, palabras-raras, dle

El otro día viendo dibujos con los peques aprendí la palabra *patagio*. Según [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagio):

> En los quirópteros y otros animales, el **patagio** (en latín *patagium*) es la membrana de piel elástica y resistente que forma la superficie del ala. [...]
>
> El patagio no es exclusivo de los quirópteros. Algunos roedores denominados como "ardillas voladoras" y otros mamíferos presentan un patagio conformado por una membrana de piel entre las extremidades y unida al cuerpo que usan para planear a modo de paracaídas.

De hecho en la serie que estábamos viendo hacían referencia al patagio de las ardillas voladoras. Sin embargo, encuentro que en el DLE esa palabra no existe. Entiendo que no está incluida en el DLE por ser una palabra muy científica, aunque tanto en Ngrams como en el CORDE aparecen algunos casos, como uno de un libro de texto para quinto de bachillerato del plan de 1957, que habla del patagio de <strike>Batman</strike> los murciélagos. De hecho, el fichero general de la RAE tiene 9 entradas para *patagio* a día de hoy. En el NTLLE se ve, en todo caso, que ningún diccionario ha recogido históricamente esta palabra. En la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España el primer caso que encuentro es [de 1931](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004912897&page=5&search=patagio&lang=es).

Estaba planteándome solicitar a la RAE la inclusión de esta voz en el DLE, pero antes me gustaría saber:

- ¿Se usa normalmente la voz *patagio* con este significado en libros de texto y científicos?
- Si no, ¿existe algún otro término que recoja el mismo significado, que esté incluido en el DLE y que sea de uso más común?

Comment: Curiosamente, en el *Diccionari de l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans* sí que se encuentra la palabra catalana "patagi" con este mismo significado.

Comment: The Latin word is apparently the correct technical term in English at least according to Wikipedia. Not sure if that would add weight to your argument with the RAE.

Comment: @mdewey:  It's indeed used in scientific contexts. See, for instance, this [paper](https://books.google.es/books?id=TN_KBP3vxg4C&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=patagium&source=bl&ots=MC7QjibPN4&sig=ACfU3U0padabY0WHVb1n-cfc_3joAnbpWw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT88z4iubpAhU18-AKHb4ODSA4FBDoATAJegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=patagium&f=false).